# How to monitor the change of the database so as to flush the treeview?

Tags: c#, database, treeview, monitor

target: whenever the table in the database changes, the treeview will reload the new contents of the table.

Is there any good methods to solve this problem?      thank u

Comment: What database are you using? What abstraction layer (if any) are you using?

Comment: the database I use is called GBase and I think we are using the application layer. Is there any method to flush the treeview only when table changes?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using SQL Server check out [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Here are links to MSDN with examples of how SqlDependency can be used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28VS.80%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I found the database I use doesn't support the class sqldependency. Is there any other methods to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking loud here.. if you can't use SqlDependency, the next thing you can try is FileWatcher, but you won't know what changed..